# How do I make a nested accordion with HTML5/CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I’ve been following this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp to make an accordion, but I can’t figure out how to put in a nested accordion within a div element. I tried the following, but the nested div element doesn’t adhere to the JavaScript at the bottom of the How To article.

```
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <button class="accordion">Subsection 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>subsection text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JavaScript at the bottom of the article:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please include the javascript in question in the body of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird. I just tried it and it works.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="accordion">Subsection 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <button class="accordion">Subsection 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, so yes, this is working exactly how I wanted it to. I supplied dummy code in lieu of my massive wall of code I'm actually using, so I compared it across, and figured out I was missing a </p> tag. I was going insane trying to figure this out, your comparison led me to the (albeit unrelated) answer. Thank you much!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the javascript. It does:

`panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";`

but the `scrollHeight` at the time of expanding does not include the expanded subsection because it is hidden. If you expand Subsection 1, then collapse and re-open Section 1 you'll see that it works fine. If you would like to get around this, add these lines of javascript after the previously mentioned line:

```
var parent = this.parentElement;
parent.style.maxHeight = parseInt(parent.style.maxHeight) + panel.scrollHeight + "px";
```

this will expand the parent `panel` based on the child `panel` height upon being expanded by targeting the panel's parent and dynamically changing the `maxHeight` property of its syle.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bn3woc8L/18/